# if statement condition isnt satisfied but still program works

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a simple code

```
def func(a,b):
    if (b>=3.0) and (b<=4.0):
        if (a>=3.0) and (a<=6.0):
            var_region='A'
        if (a>6.0) and (a<=11.0):
            var_region='B'
    if (b>4.0):
        var_region='C'

    region=var_region
    print region
    return region


Tmax=4.1
Tmin=3.0
T=Tmin
var=3.0
dT=0.1
while T<Tmax:
    calll=func(var,T)
    T=T+dT
```

The output of the program is:

```
A,A..........,C
```

In while loop, the final value of "T" is 4.0, and it prints "C" instead of "A". why is that?

Answer (score 5):

It's because floating point numbers cannot be represented precisely with `float`, so its calculation is not precise, either. `b` is not precisely `4.0`, but a floating point number that's very close to it. Adding this might help you understand:

```
if (b>4.0):
    print(repr(b))
    var_region='C'
```

Output:

```
4.000000000000001
C
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause float type is not precise in computer.

```
while T<Tmax:
    print T
    calll=func(var,T)
    T=T+dT
```

add a print statement before function calling in while loop you will find T's final value is `4.000000000000001` and the `if (b>4.0):` will get a `True` value, and caused the last output to be `C`

I recommend you using decimal to achieve what you want , that type is precise in computer

```
from decimal import Decimal
Tmax = Decimal(4.1)
......
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a quick tip - multiline code blocks can be indented by four spaces instead of using backticks.

Answer (score -1):

It's because .1 cannot be expressed exactly as a floating-point number, so the calculations don't give precisely the results you expect.  If you print b inside the function, you'll find that on the last call, the value is 4.000000000000001.  By the way, in python you don't have to write awkward stuff like

```
if (b>=3.0) and (b<=4.0):
```

You can write

```
if 3.0 <= b <= 4.0:
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a quick tip - multiline code blocks can be indented by four spaces instead of using backticks.

Comment: @Qix There's no multiline code here?  What are you talking about?

Comment: There is, it is a multiline code block that spans 1 line. ;)